# Does HBase 0.92 support Coprocessor Secondary indexes?

Tags: hbase

The documentation http://hbase.apache.org/book/secondary.indexes.html indicates that 0.92 supports Coprocessor secondary indexes. However, I cannot find any documentation about it.
Is it supported out of the box or do we have to write it on our own using Coprocessors?

Answer (score 0):

it is not currently supported out of the box.  However, there is a JIRA issue working on it:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-3340